# C# How to get soap XML from service reference (wsdl import)?

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I was given a wsdl file, I added it as a Service Reference in visual studio.

I can now create a new service client, then do the soap actions no problem.

However in C#, I need to just grab the soap request XML that it produces to do the action and store it in a variable, and not actually send it to the web service.

Is this possible to do? I tried just serializing the class to xml, but the result is a bit different from the expected soap request xml.

Comment: Just like you created service client, create a webservice too using the wsdl. Then use SoapUI to get the soap request for the web service.

Comment: @KosalaW thanks for the help. I hadn't considered creating my own web service with it. I do need to get it programmatically, though, so I think I need more than SoapUI. But perhaps the web service I create could just return the request xml, if there's no other way...

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding of your requirement, you have a wsdl and you want to know, what the soap request (xml?) will look like for each action that you are planning to implement?

Comment: @KosalaW I need to get the soap request xml as a string in c#. Edited question a bit for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

I'm still looking in to this but the best bet is to create a partial class of your web Service Reference.

In Visual Studio Solution Explorer (With your project selected), click on the Show All Files icon, this will allow you to expand the Web Service until you reach a file called `Reference.cs` (It's under the Reference.map node).

This class will be marked as `partial` and inherits from `SoapHttpClientProtocol` which should give you access to some interesting properties and methods etc.

I'll update this answer shortly when I finish exploring.

Hope it helps!

**Update;**
I found this helpful article that I think will solve the problem;

http://orbinary.com/blog/2010/01/getting-the-raw-soap-xml-sent-via-soaphttpclientprotocol/

You can use the below class to implement the XmlWriterSpy;

```
public class XmlWriterSpy : XmlWriter
{
    private readonly XmlWriter _originalWriter;
    private readonly XmlTextWriter _buffer;
    private readonly StringWriter _sw;

    public XmlWriterSpy(XmlWriter originalWriter)
    {
        _originalWriter = originalWriter;

        _sw = new StringWriter();

        _buffer = new XmlTextWriter(_sw)
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        _originalWriter.Flush();
        _buffer.Flush();
        _sw.Flush();
    }

    public string Xml => _sw?.ToString();

    public override WriteState WriteState => _originalWriter.WriteState;

    public override void Close() { _originalWriter.Close(); _buffer.Close(); }

    public override string LookupPrefix(string ns) { return _originalWriter.LookupPrefix(ns); }

    public override void WriteRaw(string data)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteRaw(data);
        _buffer.WriteRaw(data);
    }

    public override void WriteBase64(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteBase64(buffer, index, count);
        _buffer.WriteBase64(buffer, index, count);
    }


    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteString(text);
        _buffer.WriteString(text);
    }

    public override void WriteSurrogateCharEntity(char lowChar, char highChar)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteSurrogateCharEntity(lowChar, highChar);
        _buffer.WriteSurrogateCharEntity(lowChar, highChar);
    }
    public override void WriteChars(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteChars(buffer, index, count);
        _buffer.WriteChars(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteRaw(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteRaw(buffer, index, count);
        _buffer.WriteRaw(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument()
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        _buffer.WriteStartDocument();
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument(bool standalone)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteStartDocument(standalone);
        _buffer.WriteStartDocument(standalone);
    }

    public override void WriteEndDocument()
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteEndDocument();
        _buffer.WriteEndDocument();
    }

    public override void WriteDocType(string name, string pubid, string sysid, string subset)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteDocType(name, pubid, sysid, subset);
        _buffer.WriteDocType(name, pubid, sysid, subset);
    }

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
        _buffer.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteEndElement();
        _buffer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    public override void WriteFullEndElement()
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteFullEndElement();
        _buffer.WriteFullEndElement();
    }

    public override void WriteStartAttribute(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns);
        _buffer.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteEndAttribute()
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteEndAttribute();
        _buffer.WriteEndAttribute();
    }

    public override void WriteCData(string text)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteCData(text);
        _buffer.WriteCData(text);
    }

    public override void WriteComment(string text)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteComment(text);
        _buffer.WriteComment(text);
    }

    public override void WriteProcessingInstruction(string name, string text)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction(name, text);
        _buffer.WriteProcessingInstruction(name, text);
    }

    public override void WriteEntityRef(string name)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteEntityRef(name);
        _buffer.WriteEntityRef(name);
    }

    public override void WriteCharEntity(char ch)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteCharEntity(ch);
        _buffer.WriteCharEntity(ch);
    }

    public override void WriteWhitespace(string ws)
    {
        _originalWriter.WriteWhitespace(ws);
        _buffer.WriteWhitespace(ws);
    }
}
```

You then just have to inherit from the proxy generated class as shown below;

```
public class MyHelloService : HelloService
{

    private XmlWriterSpy _xmlSpy;

    public MyHelloService() : base() { }

    protected override XmlWriter GetWriterForMessage(SoapClientMessage message, int bufferSize)
    {
        _xmlSpy = new XmlWriterSpy(base.GetWriterForMessage(message, bufferSize));
        return _xmlSpy;
    }

    public string Xml => _xmlSpy?.Xml;
}
```